# Google Breakpad examples

Tags: c++, crash-reports, crash-dumps, google-breakpad

Does anyone have any examples of configurations for google breakpad? I can build it just fine, however, there is limited documentation. I would like to see examples, such as how to modify where crash reports get sent to.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with App Engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be platform-specific. On Windows, you could check out the following function in client\windows\sender\crash_report_sender.h (in particular, note the 'url' argument).

```
// Sends the specified minidump file, along with the map of
// name value pairs, as a multipart POST request to the given URL.
// Parameter names must contain only printable ASCII characters,
// and may not contain a quote (") character.
// Only HTTP(S) URLs are currently supported.  The return value indicates
// the result of the operation (see above for possible results).
// If report_code is non-NULL and the report is sent successfully (that is,
// the return value is RESULT_SUCCEEDED), a code uniquely identifying the
// report will be returned in report_code.
// (Otherwise, report_code will be unchanged.)
ReportResult SendCrashReport(const wstring &url,
                             const map<wstring, wstring> &parameters,
                             const wstring &dump_file_name,
                             wstring *report_code);
```

Does this help?